# QT QTextEdit setText crashes

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

I've created a qt widgets application. Using the design mode I've created a QTextEdit and indicated that in the header file:

```
...

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
class QAction;
class QMenu;
class QTextEdit;
QT_END_NAMESPACE

...

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QTextEdit *textEdit_2;
};
```

There is also a slot which is triggered by pushing a button. What it has to do is to insert some text into textEdit_2 after the button is pushed, still the program crashes.
In mainwindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::on_action_4_triggered()
{
    textEdit_2->setText("text");
}
```

I've also tried

```
textEdit_2->setText(QString("text"));
```

which anyway doesn't work. What's the problem?

Comment: Just want to be clear, does the program crash on start up or does it crash when you push the button?

Comment: It crashes when I push the button.

Comment: did you initialize `textEdit_2` pointer ?

Comment: I'm sorry for the dumb question, but where should it be initialized?

Comment: I was thinking if it was initialised as well but it doesn't crash on start up (making the assumption that the QTextEdit is visible). @DannyPhantom it should be initialized in the constructor by allocating a QTextEdit object on the heap e.g. textEdit_2 = new QTextEdit;

Comment: you said that used the design mode to created a QTextEdit so it should be access by `ui` pointer, eg.
`ui->myTextEdit->setText("text")`, where 'myTextEdit' is name of created QTextEdit

Comment: @Blueman wow, so that's the problem. Thanks a lot, now everything works as it should :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> textEdit_2->setText("text");

The problem is that you are trying to ignore the actual text widget created in `QtDesigner` and invent another as a class member. This is not going to fly as you seem to want it.

In order to reuse the text widget from the UI that you created with the graphical tool, you would need to reuse the `ui` object as follows:

```
ui->textEdit_2->setText("text");
```

Please also note that you do not need to construct `QString` explicitly like this:

```
textEdit_2->setText(QString("text"));
```

This will be all automatic for you.